# How do I get div to use percentage height of parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

While trying to make a full-screen page with flexbox container that has items spaced evenly I found that I cannot in any way set the height of the container to full page height. How can this simple thing not work??

I want to have the flex container cover min 100% of page height and be able to grow beyond that if needed. But a good start would just be having it be 'static' 100% height, or any percentage!

**I'm not interested in setting the height of the div to vh units !**

I put the body min-height to 100vh based on the explanation here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/html-page-width-height/

HTML:

```
<div class="first">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.first {
  min-height: 100%; /*why does this not work???*/
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage

Comment: From your link it would seem that the code should work: the parent is <body> which has an explicit height set that is indeed relative, but to the screen, therefore gets calculated to a value in pixels, which the class "first" should be able to use a percentage of, no?

Answer (score 0):

Relative height requires a non-static parent container has an explicit `height` set. Which you don't have(`min-height` doesn't count). You can either specify `height` to the `body`, or use a workaround like giving `min-height: inherit` to `.first`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.first {
  min-height: inherit;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok sure, it works in the codepen but it doesn't work in the actual app I'm making. Also, it's just a workaround, I want an actual proper solution to this which I believe CSS has to have. Or does setting the body height to 100vh and then not caring that the actual content will spill out when a scrollbar appears IS the PROPER solution? This seems like madness